# When using cross validation, is there a way to ensure each fold somehow contains at least several instances of the true class?

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I'm fitting a model using cross fold validation with caret:

```
library(caret)

## tuning & parameters
set.seed(123)
train_control <- trainControl(
  method = "cv",
  number = 5,
  savePredictions = TRUE,
  verboseIter = TRUE,
  classProbs = TRUE,
  summaryFunction = my_summary
)

linear_model = train(
  x = select(training_data, Avg_Load_Time),
  y = target,
  trControl = train_control,
  method = "glm", # logistic regression
  family = "binomial",
  metric = "ROC"
)
```

The trouble is that out of ~5K rows I have only ~120 true cases. This is throwing a warning message when using GLM via caret "glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred".

Is there a parameter I can set or some approach to ensuring each fold has some of the true cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier when you shuffle data and have enough examples of each class.

If you don't have enough examples, you can increase the size of the minority class using SMOTE (Synthetic Minority Oversampling Technique). Package `smotefamily` in R.

Then you will be able to do 5 or 10 fold Cross Validation without raising any issues.